# How can I install cv2 for python?

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to install cv2 for python. I tried with pip install, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me? The version of python I use is 3.10. If you need any more information please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: If it doesn't *seem* to work, maybe it actually did?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can install with this command line:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

here is the link:

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

If you have errors beyond this, please flag what the error is...